# add to cart products with max qty of products error with run script

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart, script

add to cart products with max qty of products with below code

```
include 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();

Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));

// Need for start the session
$cartHelper = Mage::helper('checkout/cart');
    $items = $cartHelper->getCart()->getItems();
    echo count($items);
    foreach($items as $item)
    {
        $itemId = $item->getItemId();
        $cartHelper->getCart()->removeItem($itemId)->save();
    }

try {

    $product_id = '7896'; // Replace id with your product id
    $qty = '99'; // max qty with your qty
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
    $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
    $cart->init();
    $cart->addProduct($product, array('qty' => $qty));
    $cart->save();
    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

- products qty available in store is 99 with products id - 7896
- when my script first time run add 99 qty in cart ..but  next time run its
  give error to "The requested quantity for 'xxx' is not available"

its look like run script as

1st time - working (add to cart with 99 qty)

2nd time - given error

3rd time- working (add to cart with 99 qty)

4th time - given error and

continues,,,,

I have all ready remove cart item every time before add product as you see in code ..but its not getting same response as working ..

Comment: Possible duplicate http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/102942/trucating-magento-cart-and-then-adding-product-to-cart-gives-500-error/102950?noredirect=1#comment139921_102950

Comment: check answer of that question

Comment: its not working i already checked ....

Comment: What issue you are facing ?

Comment: The requested quantity for 'xxx' is not available when run second time

Comment: check it again because it is working fine. i have updated code

Comment: not working your code with login customer ...please reply correct code...

Comment: This will not work for current login customer !!!!!

Comment: Where is this requirement in your question ?

Comment: This is just code to programmatic add product to cart

Comment: if you need to update /add product to cart for current login customer the code will be different

Comment: ok can you tell me , please ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
$session->getQuote()->delete();
$session->clear();

$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
$cart->setQuote($session->getQuote());

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product') -> load($product_id);
if ($product) {
    if ($product -> isSaleable()) {
        $cart -> addProduct($product, array('qty' => $qty));
    }
}

// $session->setCartWasUpdated(true); // Not really necessary - Vicary
$cart->save();
```